# Does there exist an operation that could turn the set of all negative real numbers into an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

The answer is no for familiar operations of addition and multiplication. But could there exist any other operation that could turn the set of all negative real numbers into an abelian group. If yes, what is it? If no, how could I prove it?

Comment: The quesion in the title is not the same as the question in the body...

Comment: My bad. I will edit the question right now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How about $x\oplus y= -|xy|$?

Comment: @saulspatz The notation of that can be simplified to $-xy$.

Comment: @J.G. Good point.

Comment: Same question as [Operation that makes the negative real numbers, $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$, a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547145/), it seems.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you genuinely allow *any* operation, then the answer is yes for a silly (but important!) reason: we can lift structure along bijections. Specifically, fix some bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{<0}$. Then we can define an addition map $\oplus$ as follows: $$a\oplus b=f(f^{-1}(a)+f^{-1}(b)).$$ The map $f$ shows that "$\mathbb{R}$ with $+$ looks identical to $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$ with $\oplus$" - or, in more precise language, the two structures $(\mathbb{R};+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{<0};\oplus)$ are **isomorphic**. A fortiori they have the same general algebraic properties: in particular, $(\mathbb{R}_{<0};\oplus)$ is an abelian group since $(\mathbb{R};+)$ is.

- A notational comment: the expression "$(A; [\DeclareMathOperator{\stuff}{stuff}\stuff])$" indicates that $A$ is the *underlying set* of the structure involved and $[\stuff]$ is the list of *operations and relations* on that set, with different things in $[\stuff]$ being separated by commas (in contrast with the semicolon separating $A$ and $[\stuff]$). So, for example, "$\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered ring" would be written as "$(\mathbb{R};+,\cdot,<)$."

Basically, when we ask "Does such-and-such structure exist on the set $X$?," all that really matters is the **cardinality** of $X$: whenever $X_1,X_2$ are in bijection with each other, the answer for $X=X_1$ will be the same as the answer for $X=X_2$.

Things get more interesting if we ask for the desired structure to satisfy some additional properties. For example, we might want the relevant operations - the (binary) group operation $\oplus$ and the corresponding (unary) inverse operation - to be **continuous** with respect to the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$. Now it's not the case that any old bijection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{<0}$ will do, since a really messy bijection might turn the *continuous* $+$ into something highly *discontinuous*; we need to be a bit more careful. As a matter of fact, however, we can find one which does the job (consider the map $f(x)=-e^x$).

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Thank you so much, Noah.

Comment: Note: this construction is commonly known as the *transport of structure*.

Comment: Is the semicolon (as opposed to a comma) really that crucial? In fact, does it change the meaning at all?

Comment: Worth noting that the $f(x)=-e^x$ generates the $x\cdot y = -xy$ of the other answers.

Answer (score 23):

A concrete example of an abelian group structure on negative reals is

$$x\circ y:=-xy$$

Answer (score 14):

If you ask whether the negative reals form a vector space over the rationals without specifying the operations, the obvious way to view the question is using the standard operations of addition and multiplication.  You point out correctly that this fails.  If you are allowed to define new operations, all that is left is the cardinality of the negative reals, which is $\mathfrak c$ like all the reals.  We know that the standard reals form a vector space over the rationals, so we just need to define a bijection $f: \Bbb{R^- \leftrightarrow R}$.  Then we define $\oplus$ on the negative reals as $x \oplus y=f^{-1}(f(x)+f(y))$ and $\otimes$ as $x \otimes y=f^{-1}(f(x)\cdot f(y))$  These operations, with $f^{-1}(0)$ as the identity for $\oplus$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ as the identity for $\otimes$ will make the negative reals a vector space over the rationals.  I leave defining scalar multiplication and inverses to you.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1.

Answer (score 6):

I add this "answer" (too long for a comment) just to make some more explicit the result used in the nice answers above.

**Claim**. Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and $\tilde G$ a set. If there is a bijection $f\colon G\to \tilde G$, then the operation:

$$\tilde g*\tilde h:=f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde h)), \space\space\space\forall \tilde g,\tilde h \in \tilde G\tag 1$$

- defines a group structure in $\tilde G$;
- $(\tilde G,*) \cong (G,\cdot)$.

*Proof*.

1. *Closure*: by definition $(1)$.
2. *Associativity*:

\begin{alignat}{1}
(\tilde g*\tilde h)*\tilde k &=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g*\tilde h)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}\color{blue}{(}f\color{cyan}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde h)\color{cyan}{)}\color{blue}{)}\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde h)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot \color{blue}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde h)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{blue}{)}\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot (f^{-1}f)\color{blue}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde h)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{blue}{)}\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}\color{blue}{(}f\color{cyan}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde h)\cdot f^{-1}(\tilde k)\color{cyan}{)}\color{blue}{)}\color{red}{)} \\
&=f\color{red}{(}f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}\color{blue}{(}\tilde h*\tilde k\color{blue}{)}\color{red}{)} \\
&=\tilde g*(\tilde h *\tilde k), \space\space\space\forall \tilde g,\tilde h,\tilde k\in \tilde G \\
\tag 2
\end{alignat}

3. *Unit*: let's define $e_{\tilde G}:= f(e_G)$; then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\tilde g * e_{\tilde G} &= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}(e_{\tilde G})) \\
&= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}(f(e_G))) \\
&= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot e_G) \\
&= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)) \\
&= \tilde g, \space\forall \tilde g \in \tilde G \\
\tag 3
\end{alignat}

and $e_{\tilde G}$ nicely behaves as unit.

4. *Inverse*: $\forall \tilde g \in \tilde G$, let's define $\tilde g^{-1}:=f((f^{-1}(\tilde g))^{-1})$; then:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\tilde g*\tilde g^{-1} &= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot f^{-1}\color{red}{(}f((f^{-1}(\tilde g))^{-1})\color{red}{)}) \\
&= f(f^{-1}(\tilde g)\cdot (f^{-1}(\tilde g))^{-1}) \\
&= f(e_G) \\
&= e_{\tilde G}, \space\forall \tilde g \in \tilde G \\
\tag 4
\end{alignat}

and $\tilde g^{-1}$ nicely behaves as inverse of $\tilde g$.

Therefore, $(\tilde G, *)$ is a group. Finally, $\psi:=f^{-1}$ is a group homomorphism, because (by $(1)$) $\psi(\tilde g*\tilde h)=\psi(\tilde g)\cdot \psi(\tilde h), \space\forall \tilde g,\tilde h\in \tilde G$, and thence $(\tilde G,*)\cong (G,\cdot)$.

---

**Example**

$(G,\cdot)=(\mathbb{R},+)$, $\space\space\tilde G=\mathbb{R}_{<0}$, $\space\space v=f(x)=-\operatorname{exp}(x)$. Then:

- Group operation (see $(1)$):
  \begin{alignat}{1}
  v*w &= -\operatorname{exp}(x+y) \\
  &= -\operatorname{exp}(x)\operatorname{exp}(y) \\
  &= -vw
  \end{alignat}
- Unit:

$$0_{(\mathbb{R}_{<0},*)}=-\operatorname{exp}(0)=-1$$

- Inverse:

$$v^{-1}=-\operatorname{exp}(-x)$$

By the claim:

$$(\mathbb{R}_{<0},*,-1)\cong (\mathbb{R},+,0)$$

Comment: As noted by *Wojowu* under *Noah Schweber's* answer the general procedure of inducing structure via a bijective set-function is known as *transport of structure*. As the principle is applied and carried out in detail here I thought it might be worth remarking. (+1) nevertheless!