# Repeatedly Iterating an $\mathbb{N}-$Bijection

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be a bijection. Consider sequences of the form
$\left(n,\phi(n),\phi(\phi(n)),...\right).$ For any n, must it be true that this sequence terminates or cycles? Intuitively it seems true, I tried to explicitly construct some counter examples, only for them to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, this is just an application of the more general fact in Noah’s answer, but in case you wanted something concrete, consider the map $$n\ \mapsto\ \begin{cases}n-2&\text{ if }n\text{ is even and at least }2 \\ 1&\text{ if }n=0 \\ n+2&\text{ if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases},$$ which has inverse $$n\ \mapsto\ \begin{cases}n+2&\text{ if }n\text{ is even} \\ 0&\text{ if }n=1 \\ n-2&\text{ if }n\text{ is odd and at least }3\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Fix your favorite bijection $b:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Each permutation $\pi$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ "pulls back" to a permutation $\pi_b$ of $\mathbb{N}$ as follows: given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, apply $b$ then apply $\pi$ then un-apply $b$. In symbols, I'm talking about the permutation $$b^{-1}\circ\pi\circ b$$ (remember that composition notation is right-to-left).

The point is that $\pi_b$ shares all the basic combinatorial properties of $\pi$ itself; in particular, if $\pi$ has no finite cycles, then neither will $\pi_b$. We can use this to solve your question quite easily: just look at $(+1)_b$.

By replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with other countably infinite sets, we can similarly get concrete examples of weird bijections. For instance, maybe you want the *orbit equivalence relation* to have infinitely many classes (to contrast with the fact that any two things in $\mathbb{Z}$ can be gotten from each other by applying $(+1)$ some (possibly-negative-)integer number of times). Well, in this case start with a bijection $b:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ instead, and let $\pi$ be the "plus-one" map on $\mathbb{Q}$. This $\pi$ won't let us "connect" $1$ and ${1\over 2}$ (say) no matter how many times we apply it to either.

In general, questions of the type you're asking **only depend on the cardinality of the set involved**. This is itself a case of a more general phenomenon, of **isomorphism-independence**; over time, you'll develop a sense of what sort of structure is relevant to a given problem. (The discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3736873/does-there-exist-an-operation-that-could-turn-the-set-of-all-negative-real-numbe) may also be useful.)

Comment: Looks good. Thank you.