# Does a permutation necessarily fix some set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a permutation: $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, does there necessarily exist some $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, such that $\sigma(X)=X$.

This is a question that came while I was trying to solve another problem, what I tried to do is find some $X=[1,n]$ for some positive integer $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ It would be enough, to prove that there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\le N, \sigma(n)\le N$

This didn't lead me anywhere, and I'm not sure if the result holds.

Comment: As the question is stated, it is enough to take $X=\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I just realized that the below-linked question is an exact duplicate of this one; I've voted to close this one as a dupe, and meanwhile I've made this answer CW to avoid double rep gain.*

---

Of course the problem is trivial as stated - take $X=\mathbb{N}$ or $X=\emptyset$. Based on the context provided, I suspect that the goal is to get a *finite and nonempty* set which is stable under the permutation.

This is in general impossible, and the easiest way to see this is to shift from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. It's a standard exercise to construct a bijection $b$ between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, and each permutation $\pi$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ "lifts" along this bijection to a permutation $b^{-1}\pi b$ of $\mathbb{N}$ with the same general characteristics (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740313/repeatedly-iterating-an-mathbbn-bijection/4740320#4740320) for another example of how this can play out). In particular, the **shift function** on the integers $$z\mapsto z+1$$ has no finite stable set, and from this we get a (messier but still not too hard to write down) permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ with only two stable sets, $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{N}$.

Alternatively, here's a way to describe such a permutation without "passing to $\mathbb{Z}$" (and using the convention that $0\in\mathbb{N}$):

> Send each odd $x$ to $x+2$, send $0$ to $1$, and send each even $x>0$ to $x-2$.